# Firefox V IE downloading

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-11

I am running the latest versions of Firefox and IE.
It seems that IE is much quicker and more resilient at downloading
Large files (over 700Mb).
Does anyone have any ideas, or suggestions why this should be?
Regards
Dayman

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly because of either

- The UserAgents
- IE doing multithreading
- IE lying about download speeds

OK, let's start at point one

Firefox VS IE UserAgents shouldn't make a difference, but it depends on what the server is actually favoring

IE doing multithreading: Same as using a download manager such as DownThemAll! in Firefox.

IE lying about download speeds: this is actually much more common than you'd think. IE has a bug where it will report the amount downloaded as its speed, for example at 16% IE starts with 1.70MB/s and after 15 seconds it jumps to 30MB/s which is false.

Comment: IE may be lying about the speed, but it is definitely downloading faster,  more importantly IE seems to be more reliable. Firefox downloads just stop on an often but irregular basis!